# mysql order by best match and order by field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Below is my query for search keyword and then `ORDER BY FIELd`

```
SELECT * FROM mall WHERE mall_status = '1' AND 
(mall_name LIKE '%Cap%' OR mall_name LIKE '%Square%' OR mall_name = 'Cap Square' OR 
tag LIKE 'Cap Square,%' OR tag LIKE '%,Cap Square' OR tag LIKE '%, Cap Square' OR tag LIKE '%,Cap Square,%' OR tag LIKE '%, Cap Square,%' OR tag = 'Cap Square' ) 
ORDER BY FIELD(state_id, 14, 10, 5, 4, 1, 6, 11, 3, 2, 7, 8, 15, 12, 13) ASC , mall_name LIMIT 0,30
```

and the result will show based on `state_id` order, but now how to return **best matches for first row only** and then follow by state_id( `ORDER BY FIELD` ) . Best match is something like `mall_name = 'Cap Square'` .

so the result is something like this :

```
Cap Square (state id: 10)
Central Square (state id: 14)
Berjaya Times Square (state id: 14)
Oasis Square (state id: 10)
Shaftsbury (state id: 5)
Penang Times Square (state id: 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the ordering like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mall
WHERE mall_status = '1' AND 
      (mall_name LIKE '%Cap%' OR mall_name LIKE '%Square%' OR mall_name = 'Cap Square' OR 
       tag LIKE 'Cap Square,%' OR tag LIKE '%,Cap Square' OR tag LIKE '%, Cap Square' OR
       tag LIKE '%,Cap Square,%' OR tag LIKE '%, Cap Square,%' OR tag = 'Cap Square'
      ) 
ORDER BY mall_name = 'Cap Square' desc,
         FIELD(state_id, 14, 10, 5, 4, 1, 6, 11, 3, 2, 7, 8, 15, 12, 13) ASC , mall_name
LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```